# How to change rtl direction to ltr in codesample plugin of tinymce

Tags: django, tinymce-plugins, django-tinymce

My Django-TinyMCE direction has turned rtl due to my language and everything looks fine except the codesample plugin which has gotten rtl and scrambles the code. I would appreciate anyone help me figure this out. I want code sample to be ltr while everything else is rtl.

Thanks in advance

images ...

[rtl text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6CUL.png)
[I want rtl to ltr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9z1C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with this style in head of my html code:

```
    .tox .tox-form__group--stretched .tox-textarea {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: left;
        direction: ltr !important;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `directionality` to the list of plugins and `ltr rtl` to the toolbar.

Then, before adding the code block set the direction to LTR.

See a working sample [here](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/46haab/1).

Comment: I did this but it was not resolved
image ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9z1C.png

Comment: I use that package too. Add the plugin and toolbar item and then use it.

Comment: I use language: "fa" in initial tinymce and this causes this to happen. How do I solve it?